# Creating a folder and a filename for the Ansible output failing

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get an output to a file using a Jinja2 template. However the last task 'Write to the file' fails. The idea is to create a dynamic folder based on `m-d-yyyy--Hr:Min` as the task is running on the same set of devices. Therefore they will be saved to folders based on date and time. The folder gets created. But the file is not. Also if I go to a static folder and use it in a "dest" it also works. Can someone please provide a direction? Thank you in advance.

```yaml
      - name: Create directory
        file:
          path: ./config-backups/{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y--%H:%M') }}
          mode: 0755
          recurse: yes
        register: folder_name_with_date
    
      - name: Write to the file
        ansible.builtin.template:
          src: ./templates/show_run.j2
          dest: ./{{folder_name_with_date}}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-running-config-{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y--%H:%M') }}.txt
          newline_sequence: '\r\n'
```

Error

> fatal: [10.6.66.66]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "699bd34165f85658300254daf40e5322cf7faaa", "msg": "Destination directory ./{'path': './config-backups/03-17-2021--09:58', 'changed': True, 'diff': {'before': {'path': './config-backups/03-17-2021--09:58', 'state': 'absent', 'mode': '0775'}, 'after': {'path': './config-backups/03-17-2021--09:58', 'state': 'directory', 'mode': '0755'}}, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 1000, 'owner': 'xxxx', 'group': 'xxxx', 'mode': '0755', 'state': 'directory', 'size': 4096, 'failed': False} does not exist"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Destination directory ./{'path': './config-backups/03-17-2021--09:58' ... does not exist"}**"*

A: If you want to create a directory it's necessary to set the attribute `state=directory`. The default [state](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-state) is `file`. Create the variable with the name of the directory first. Then use it in the playbook. Given the template

```yaml
shell> cat templates/show_run.j2 
This is show_run.j2
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Set name of the directory
      set_fact:
        folder_name_with_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y--%H:%M') }}"
    - name: Create directory
      file:
        state: directory
        path: ./config-backups/{{ folder_name_with_date }}
        mode: 0755
    - name: Write to the file
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: ./templates/show_run.j2
        dest: "./config-backups/{{ folder_name_with_date }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-running-config-{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y--%H:%M') }}.txt"
        newline_sequence: '\r\n'
```

gives

```sh
shell> tree config-backups
config-backups
└── 03-17-2021--16:42
    └── localhost-running-config-03-17-2021--16:42.txt
```

```sh
shell> cat config-backups/03-17-2021--16\:42/localhost-running-config-03-17-2021--16\:42.txt 
This is show_run.j2
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for valuable answers!

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable you are registering as `folder_name_with_date` is a list of items, not just a string. You need to get just the path variable from your `folder_name_with_date` list. Call it via `folder_name_with_date.path` to get the path you are looking for.

Also, because you are trying to concatenate variables with a string, I would recommend encapsulating your entire statement with `"`'s, like so: `dest: "./{{folder_name_with_date.path}}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-running-config-{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y--%H:%M') }}.txt"`

Not entirely sure whether adding the `"`'s or not is necessary, but be sure to get the `folder_name_with_date`'s `.path` instead.

**EDIT:** For the future, I would recommend outputting what your variables look like after you create them, so you can see how to use them in future tasks. Technically, Ansible will output what the variable is when it is registered, but I also like to include a quick debug like this to view my variables:

```
name: what is my variables structure??
debug: 
  msg: "{{ folder_name_with_date }}"
```

Debug documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html